# Distinct SQL / PHP Behaviour (Only 1 Row Returned)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, distinct

Bit of an issue with my PHP / SQL here. This is the code:

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT student FROM classes LIMIT 100";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row);
```

Having run the query manually I get about 40 returned values. All good there. However when I do the print_r, I'm only getting the first returned value i.e. The $row array only has one entry. Link and db are fine, it just appears to be my array handling.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` only retrieves one row at a time. In order to get all rows you need to use a loop like `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mysqli_fetch_array` only fetches one row at a time.  Consider using it in a loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the returned rows. Try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT student FROM classes LIMIT 100";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```